# Continuous and non differentiable functions

Tags: calculus

Can I generate a continuous and non-differentiable function with basic calculus tools?
Is there a simple way of expressing such a function?

Comment: Non-differentiable everywhere? At a point? What do you mean by "basic calculus tools"?

Comment: It was supposed to be a function ND at infinite if not at all points in x-y plane.Soryy<I coud'nt put my point clearly.

Comment: I spelt sorry wrongly.By the waycan you tell me what's the difference between a class and a set?

Answer (score 5):

The function $|x|$ is (uniformly) continuous everywhere, but not differentiable at $0$, because it has a corner. Finite sums of this function can give continuous maps which are not differentiable at any given finite set, and careful scaling can extend this to countable sets.

A continuous function which is nowhere differentiable is [harder to construct](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_function), but quite doable with infinite series.

Comment: That was helpful.I realize that I was dumb enough to miss that point.

Comment: If $\psi(x) = 1_{[-1,1]}(x)(1-|x|) $, and we let $f(x)=\sum_n \psi(x-n)$, then $f$ is not differentiable on $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Yeah! something that uses the same concept on ND of modulus at a point